# Passing a large text back to the server? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, .net, html, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a project now where I will have a large chunk of CSV text, like 60 lines or more, and need to pass that from the client to the server. I know it would be weird with GET, but how would I store the multiline text so that I could later split it up, etc at my application?

The application needs 2 parameters, the CSV info and a product number parameter. I want to do this via JQuery AJAX call.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just POST the data via AJAX and you don't have to worry about base64 encoding. The newlines you'll get as "\n" encoded in your POST body.

Sample jQuery code, that posts the value of a multi line textarea (description) to the server:

```
$.post('1', { description: $('#Description').val(), name: $('#Name').val() });
```

When displaying the data you'll need to replace the '\n' newlines with 
 HTML tags.

HTTP does not limit the size on the POST data, but a browser may do.

Answer (score 2):

First you should use POST to send the data, not GET. I am assuming that you don't want to pass it as a file, but in a single CGI variable.  So the easiest thing would be to base64 encode it, send it along using POST (Jquery AJAX call will do that for you) and base64 decode it on server side and you'll receive it there new-lines and all.

Comment: Didn't work, for some reason, my AJAX call is stripping out all the newlines, I tried encoding it, json stringify, just letting it do a post, nothing.